# extract fitted values for each group variable in panel data

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a panel data set with a large number of groups. I calculated fitted values for each group and I would like to combine all fitted values into a new data set. I am looking for a possible shortcut to avoid having to do this manually.

The following data set is similar to the one I am working on (much smaller scale in terms of groups though).

```
set.seed(999)
dt <- data.frame("Group"=rep((LETTERS[1:10]), each=15),
  "Year"=2001:2015,"value"=5+rnorm(150, 3,1))
names(dt)
head(dt)
table(dt$Year, dt$Group)
library(reshape2)
dt_tbl1 <- dcast(dt,Year~Group)
dt_tbl1
library(forecast)
tsMat <- ts(dcast(dt, Year ~ Group), start=2001, freq=1)
dt_ses <- lapply(tsMat, function(x) ses(x))
```

I am looking for some help to automate the following step. Add all remaining groups in the data frame.

```
dt_tbl2 <- data.frame("Year"=2001:2015,
data.frame(dt_ses$A$fitted),
data.frame(dt_ses$B$fitted),
data.frame(dt_ses$C$fitted))
```

And rename the variables in the new data set to relate to the original groups

```
names(dt_tbl2)[2:4] <- c("A_hat", "B_hat", "C_hat")
```

Once this is completed the dt_tbl2 should have the same format like the dt_tbl1.

I have tried to use sapply() and lapply() but nothing seems to be working.
Thanks
TCS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt_tbl = data.frame(Year = c(tsMat[,1]), 
                    sapply(colnames(tsMat)[-1], function(col) {dt_ses[[col]]$fitted}))

names(dt_tbl)[-1] = paste0(names(dt_tbl)[-1], "_hat")
```

> ```
>    Year    A_hat    B_hat    C_hat    D_hat    E_hat    F_hat    G_hat    H_hat    I_hat    J_hat
> 1  2001 7.618084 7.521736 8.709448 7.967254 8.096049 7.932307 7.997542 7.552510 7.855070 8.136634
> 2  2002 7.662074 7.521647 9.150131 7.967285 8.095947 7.932320 7.997708 7.552295 7.855037 8.136680
> 3  2003 7.234079 7.521702 9.005576 7.967083 8.096054 7.932381 7.997711 7.552369 7.855063 8.136535
> 4  2004 7.919614 7.521760 8.787972 7.967088 8.096149 7.932181 7.997613 7.552552 7.854865 8.136433
> 5  2005 8.073512 7.521898 8.865025 7.967149 8.096250 7.932232 7.997742 7.552446 7.854703 8.136329
> 6  2006 7.919455 7.521738 8.572195 7.967149 8.096238 7.932222 7.997629 7.552423 7.854840 8.136423
> 7  2007 7.706265 7.521663 7.864789 7.967141 8.096114 7.932165 7.997734 7.552438 7.854872 8.136405
> 8  2008 7.010270 7.521775 7.802812 7.967079 8.095963 7.932270 7.997677 7.552331 7.854913 8.136533
> 9  2009 6.888603 7.521787 7.992457 7.967257 8.095926 7.932154 7.997648 7.552284 7.854947 8.136511
> 10 2010 6.951684 7.521864 8.130820 7.967297 8.095874 7.932169 7.997624 7.552245 7.855069 8.136587
> 11 2011 6.919762 7.521800 7.726980 7.967294 8.095964 7.932056 7.997646 7.552268 7.855106 8.136625
> 12 2012 7.976188 7.521912 7.670982 7.967325 8.095944 7.932025 7.997481 7.552206 7.855076 8.136553
> 13 2013 8.045479 7.521849 7.759875 7.967385 8.095928 7.932168 7.997529 7.552346 7.855074 8.136648
> 14 2014 8.437745 7.521808 7.485442 7.967260 8.096013 7.932149 7.997449 7.552503 7.855118 8.136644
> 15 2015 8.321283 7.521701 7.328202 7.967307 8.095962 7.932257 7.997381 7.552420 7.855088 8.136548
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `transpose` from `purrr` package, which transposes nested lists.

```
library(purrr)
t_dt_ses <- transpose(dt_ses)
dt_tbl3 <- data.frame(t_dt_ses$fitted)

# update the year column
dt_tbl3$Year<- 2001:2015

head(dt_tbl3)
#   Year        A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H        I        J
# 1 2001 7.618084 7.521736 8.709448 7.967254 8.096049 7.932307 7.997542 7.552510 7.855070 8.136634
# 2 2002 7.662074 7.521647 9.150131 7.967285 8.095947 7.932320 7.997708 7.552295 7.855037 8.136680
# 3 2003 7.234079 7.521702 9.005576 7.967083 8.096054 7.932381 7.997711 7.552369 7.855063 8.136535
# 4 2004 7.919614 7.521760 8.787972 7.967088 8.096149 7.932181 7.997613 7.552552 7.854865 8.136433
# 5 2005 8.073512 7.521898 8.865025 7.967149 8.096250 7.932232 7.997742 7.552446 7.854703 8.136329
# 6 2006 7.919455 7.521738 8.572195 7.967149 8.096238 7.932222 7.997629 7.552423 7.854840 8.136423
```